# The best way to sort a collection in a CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to sort a collection in a `Marionette.CompositeView`.
I have a collection which looks like this:

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'bar'},
   {id: 2, name: 'boo' },
   {id: 3, name: 'foo' }
]
```

I need to sort the collection by id in reverse order.
Actually it work only when I reload the page.
When I add a new model, the new item is added apparently random to the list.
If I refresh the page, they will be well sorted.

My questions are:
1) how to fix the problem when I add a new model?
2) it will be possible to improve the code?

---

Here is my code:

```
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    onRender: function () {
        var collection =  this.collection;

        collection.comparator = function (collection) {
            return - collection.get('id');
        }
    },

    onSuccess: function () {
        this.collection.add(this.messageModel);
        this.collection.sort(); // the messageModel seems to be added 
                                // apparently randomly to the list. 
                                // only if I refresh the page it will be ok
    }
})
```

Answer (score 14):

For Marionette **>= 2.0**, `CollectionView` and `CompositeView` [maintain sorting by default](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#marionettecollectionview).

For Marionette **< 2.0 and >= 1.3.0**:

```
var MySortedView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  // ...

  appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index) {
    // Already sorted when buffering.
    if (collectionView.isBuffering) {
      Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.prototype.appendHtml.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    else {
      var childrenContainer = $(collectionView.childrenContainer || collectionView.el);
      var children = childrenContainer.children();
      if (children.size() === index) {
        childrenContainer.append(itemView.el);
      } else {
        childrenContainer.children().eq(index).before(itemView.el);
      } 
    }
  }

});
```

For Marionette **< 2.0 or < 1.3.0** (same as before without buffering):

```
var MySortedView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  // ...

  appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index) {
    var childrenContainer = $(collectionView.childrenContainer || collectionView.el);
    var children = childrenContainer.children();
    if (children.size() === index) {
      childrenContainer.append(itemView.el);
    } else {
      childrenContainer.children().eq(index).before(itemView.el);
    } 
  }

});
```

It's the same for CollectionView and CompositeView.

Comment: the github link is dead :-(

Comment: the github link is not dead anymore :-)

Comment: Github link is again dead.

Comment: The wiki was removed, because V2 is now the standard library which handles this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Marionette guys are considering building this into Marionette, but until that time, I've build a little mixin called [**Sorted**](https://github.com/gitterHQ/sorted) which you can mix into your `CollectionView` and `CompositeView` classes. It's been heavily used in a production environment for [Gitter](https://gitter.im) for a long time and we find it works very well..

Answer (score 1):

Can you declare the .comparator when you create the collection? from your code the .comparator exists only on local variable `var collection` inside onRender function. If defined correctly the collection must be automatically sorted and you do not need to call .sort after adding new model

```
var Chapters = new Backbone.Collection({
    comparator = function(chapter) {
        return chapter.get("id");
    };
});
```